# iOS Ad-hoc Distribution with Google MLKit cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, ad-hoc-distribution, google-mlkit

I have a problem with using `Google MLKit` framework inside my iOS app. I use Ad-hoc OTA distribution to test the app on selected tester devices. It worked great until I added `Google MLKit` through cocoapods and I'm not really sure what is the reason. Everything compiles properly, Archive is generated without errors but when testers want to download the app it crashes during the "Installing" stage and shows "Unable to install..." alert.

Few things that I tried already :

- changing pods Embed type from "Embed and sign" to "Embed without signing"
- changing signing from "Apple Developer" to "Apple Distribution" in pods `Build Settings` for `Release` scheme
- enabling and disabling Bitcode in MLKit pods

The weird thing is that it downloads properly from Ad-hoc OTA on the device that I use to test it directly from Xcode (but I delete the app before downloading it from the server) but doesn't work on any other device.

Comment: Theres a mac app called "console" from apple, can't remember if its installed by default or not. Get one of the devices it doesn't work on, connect it to your mac with console open. Try to do the install and the detailed error should show up inside console. If its working on your device and not someone else's, its some kind of signing issue, like you have a cert installed on your phone that others don't.

Comment: Thank you @SimonMcLoughlin! That gives me a bit more information. The error says: "Failed to verify code signature of /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.......A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.". Is there a way to add my provisional profile for Pods so they will work in Ad-hoc distribution ? When I check this framework signing in Xcode it says: "Provisioning Profile: None Required"

Comment: When using cocoapods, you shouldn't need to modify any of these settings. When you include cocoapods, it gives you a workspace and puts your project inside it. You should set the provisioning profile and team etc on the workspace. Doing that and all the default cocoapods settings should be fine

Comment: That's what I thought but when I installed MLKit Pod, I have now Pods->Products->Pods-MyAppName.framework and the provisioning profile error when installing the app is for this framework

Comment: Maybe start again fresh with your project to avoid any conflicting settings, unless theres something unique about this pod (which should be called out in their setup guide), you shouldn't need to touch anything with the pods. Looking at my project using cocoapods, when I select the project and choose the main target inside the general tab. My cocoapods framework  "Pods_<projectname>.framework" is set to "Do Not Embed". You mentioned above that yours was set to Embed, maybe this is the issue

Comment: Thanks a lot @SimonMcLoughlin, checking "Do Not Embed" solved the issue ! Can you type it in as an answer to my question so I'll mark it as solved, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To find the specific error details:**

Theres a mac app called "console" from apple, can't remember if its installed by default or not. Get one of the devices it doesn't work on, connect it to your mac with console open. Try to do the install and the detailed error should show up inside console. If its working on your device and not someone else's, its some kind of signing issue, like you have a cert installed on your phone that others don't.

**Fixing the provisioning issue:**

Go to your project, select the main target under the general tab. Scroll down to "frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content". Make sure the cocoapods library called "Pods_|project-name|.framework" is set to "Do Not Embed"